# Abrir e fechar div com recurso slideToggle do jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Tenho a seguinte estrutura:

```
<div class="menu-item">
  <div class="botão"></div>
  <div class="sub-item></div>
</div>
<div class="menu-item">
  <div class="botão"></div>
  <div class="sub-item></div>
</div>
<div class="menu-item">
  <div class="botão"></div>
  <div class="sub-item></div>
</div>
```

Quando clico na div com a classe botao, a div sub-item abre com recuso slideToggle do jquery, eu gostaria que conforme eu clicasse em uma outra div com classe botao a div sub-item aberta que estivesse aberta, fechasse.

Já usei o sibling() e não funcionou

Alguém poderia me ajudar? Obrigado

Comment: O que você está procurando não seria o `Accordion`? Exemplo no [JQuery UI](https://jqueryui.com/accordion/)

Comment: fecha todas pela classe antes de abrir a nova

Comment: Não entendi wess?

Comment: Sim Victor, é quase um accordion, mas não posso usar jquery ui

Comment: "...não posso usar jquery ui"...ta escrevendo o próprio framework? Tem um pessoal bom aqui na página que tem o próprio framework. Se for o caso sucesso e mande uma versão quando ficar pronto.

Answer (score 1):

Começo por dizer que tinha umas `"` em falta na sua estrutura de exemplo.

Quanto ao problema em si é mais facil resolver fazendo `slideUp` e `slideDown` manualmente. Quando clica num elemento faz `slideUp` a todos, que só irá afetar aquele que está para baixo e faz `slideDown` ao que foi clicado.

Exemplo:

```js
$(".botão").on("click", function(){
  $(".sub-item").slideUp();
  $(this).next().slideDown();
});
```

```css
.sub-item {
  display:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="menu-item">
  <div class="botão">item 1</div>
  <div class="sub-item">subitem1</div>
</div>
<div class="menu-item">
  <div class="botão">item 2</div>
  <div class="sub-item">subitem2</div>
</div>
<div class="menu-item">
  <div class="botão">item 3</div>
  <div class="sub-item">subitem3</div>
</div>
```

Se utilizar `slideToggle` ao invés de `slideDown` irá ter exatamente o mesmo efeito, mas acaba por talvez ser mais confuso porque irá apenas sempre abrir e nunca fechar, logo corresponde sempre apenas a `slideDown`.

---

Como já foi referido em comentários não convem reinventar a roda e o que está a tentar construir já existe e é chamado de acordião. O JQuery UI já tem de facto isso nos plugins deles já contemplando várias configurações possíveis como:

- Ícones personalizados
- Menus colapsaveis
- Sem tamanho automático
- Ordenável

[Referência para o JQuery UI Accordion](https://jqueryui.com/accordion/)

Comment: Isac, não quero reinventar a roda, simplesmente por decisão de um superior não posso usar jQuery UI